# What is the difference between using `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0` vs `XACT_ABORT` approach to rollback transaction? When do I use either of this approach?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are 2 ways to rollback a transaction when there is an error (Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples):

Example 1 using @@TRANCOUNT:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
  
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a constraint violation error.  
    DELETE FROM Production.Product  
    WHERE ProductID = 980;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
  
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
END CATCH;  
  
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
GO
```

Example 2 using XACT_ABORT:

```
-- Check to see whether this stored procedure exists.  
IF OBJECT_ID (N'usp_GetErrorInfo', N'P') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo;  
GO  
  
-- Create procedure to retrieve error information.  
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo  
AS  
    SELECT   
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_LINE () AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
GO  
  
-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will cause the transaction to be uncommittable  
-- when the constraint violation occurs.   
SET XACT_ABORT ON;  
  
BEGIN TRY  
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
        -- A FOREIGN KEY constraint exists on this table. This   
        -- statement will generate a constraint violation error.  
        DELETE FROM Production.Product  
            WHERE ProductID = 980;  
  
    -- If the DELETE statement succeeds, commit the transaction.  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.  
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;  
  
    -- Test XACT_STATE:  
        -- If 1, the transaction is committable.  
        -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should   
        --     be rolled back.  
        -- XACT_STATE = 0 means that there is no transaction and  
        --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.  
  
    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.  
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT  
            N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +  
            'Rolling back transaction.'  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    END;  
  
    -- Test whether the transaction is committable.
    -- You may want to commit a transaction in a catch block if you want to commit changes to statements that ran prior to the error.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT  
            N'The transaction is committable.' +  
            'Committing transaction.'  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
    END;  
END CATCH;  
GO
```

What is the difference between these approaches in terms of when do I make use of which approach?

Comment: Start with Erland's discussion on [error handling](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html).

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` should nearly always be `ON`. Not a massive fan of all that error handling, why would you want to `COMMIT` after an error, and why swallow the exception and `SELECT` only the first error data, best off just letting the exception bubble out (`XACT_ABORT ON` means automatic rollback anyway).

Comment: These both examples are from the msdn link.

Answer (score 0):

One of the differences is the 'try catch' doesn't catch the schema related errors. If you put the first structure into a stored procedure where table doesn't exist then catch block won't be hit thus sessions turn out with an open transaction. If you put the second structure into a stored procedure then 'set xact_abort on' is going to rollback transactions under the same circumstances.

dbo.SP_Test_1

```
Create Procedure dbo.SP_Test_1 As
Go
Alter Procedure dbo.SP_Test_1
As

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a constraint violation error.  
    DELETE FROM Production.NoExistTable  
    WHERE ProductID = 980;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
END CATCH;  

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
GO
```

dbo.SP_Test_2

```
Create Procedure dbo.SP_Test_2 As
Go
Alter Procedure dbo.SP_Test_2
As

SET XACT_ABORT ON;  

BEGIN TRY  
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
              
    DELETE FROM Production.NoExistTable WHERE ProductID = 980;  

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;   

    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT  
            N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +  
            'Rolling back transaction.'  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    END;  

    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT  
            N'The transaction is committable.' +  
            'Committing transaction.'  
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
    END;  
END CATCH;  
GO
```

Comment: So is it better to always use the 2nd approach?

Comment: In most cases the 2nd pattern with 'SET XACT_ABORT ON' is more consistent approach to handle errors.